# Async action "MODIFY_FIELD" getting resolved after action "UPDATE_DATA" Redux-Thunks

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have got an action "MODIFY_FIELD" firing on blur of div which can be modified by user. This action updates redux object containing data which will be passed to backend on submit. Since it has some sanitization logic regarding content of div, seems like it has got a delay to update redux object.

Therefore, when you click on save button, it fires an action "UPDATE_DATA", which sends old data to backend, which was in redux before modification of div.

The problem is that, I need somehow to check that "MODIFY_FIELD" action has finished and only then fire action "UPDATE_DATA".

Approach .then() does not make a sense here since I am not gonna fire "UPDATE_DATA" each time then "MODIFY_FIELD" happens.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. If the question is about your code please include the relevant lines. Please also read the guidelines [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). To your question: Why can't you just check for the condition in your `.then()` callback and only dispatch `UPDATE_DATA` if the condition is met?

Comment: You could add a flag at least and check if it is to be called or not.